# TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I received this error in the next function:

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
```

```
$(".gem").live("click", function () {
    if (gameState == "pick") {
        posY = $(this).position().top;
        posX = $(this).position().left;
        $("#marker").show();
        $("#marker").css("top", posY - 5).css("left", posX - 5);
        if (selectedRow == -1) {
            selectedRow = (posY - 10) / 60;
            selectedCol = (posX - 10) / 60;
        } else {
            posY = (posY - 10) / 60;
            posX = (posX - 10) / 60;
            if ((Math.abs(selectedRow - posY) == 1 && selectedCol == posX) || (Math.abs(selectedCol - posX) == 1 && selectedRow == posY)) {
                $("#marker").hide();
                gameState = "switch";
                gemSwitch();
            } else {
                selectedRow = posY;
                selectedCol = posX;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? If it is one of the latest you need to switch to on() instead of live().

Comment: Simply googling your error `$(...).live is not a function` solve your issue... [See here.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%24(...).live+is+not+a+function&oq=%24(...).live+is+not+a+function&aqs=chrome..69i57.518j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing `live` with `on` in your code

```
$(".gem").live("click",function(){
```

replace with

```
$(".gem").on("click",function(){
```

`.live()` is **deprecated** in older version(1.7 onwards) of JQuery so you need to use `.on()`

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery on method

```
$(".gem").on('click', function() { ... });
```

https://api.jquery.com/on/

https://api.jquery.com/live/ - deprecated

Answer (score 0):

.live() is deprecated, change it to .on()

Answer (score 0):

> live is not a function

So look it up in the jQuery documentation.

A [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+live&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=FqdfU4HWCILY8geuxoCgBQ) gives [the API page](https://api.jquery.com/live/) which says:

> version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

and

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Already removed in the newest version. Use

```
$(".gem").on('click', '<insert element containing .gem here>', function(){
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/
look for "Direct and delegated events"

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on my Weblog and this was creating a problem of when clicking in "Select All" in the Updates page, wouldn't select all

[image]

From the Console could see that error and instructions pointing to the file update-core.php. Clicking there, it'd open the file in Source

[image: Fast Carousel problem]

and the problem is in

```
$('#fastcarousel-generator-insert').live('click', function(event) {
```

that should have been

```
$('#fastcarousel-generator-insert').on('click', function(event) {
```

Going to that specific file on my server and searching for `.live` wasn't enough because there was no such line in there. Then, spotted from the sentence with `.live` that it had `#fastcarousel` in it.

After disabling that plugin, then the "Select All" functionality started working again.